# Is it a good idea to build a small scale ozone AOP reactor in my garage?

Tags: home-experiment, safety, water-treatment, ozone

I have some interesting findings from my work (no conflict of interest), and I have been thinking to build an ozone lab in my garage to verify my ideas. What safety issues should I be aware of?

The purpose of the lab is to study some water/wastewater treatment process with ozone injection and advanced oxidation process. No pure oxygen or hydrogen, the power supply will be 110v, and I don't think there will be any explosive chemicals.

In term of safety, I think I need at least a fire extinguisher, basic safety wears, and an air vent to outside. Anything else?

Comment: By "air vent", I hope you mean a certified fume hood suitable for your process ;)

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea to me. Ozone is very reactive chemically. It wouldn't be good for your lungs and it would corrode/degrade almost anything that it comes in contact with in the garage. So you'd need a good vent hood with a vent stack 10 feet above your house.

Comment: The UV light is also rather reactive. You'd need to be particularity careful about eye exposure.

Comment: It's an empathetic **no** from me. How would you feel if your neighbour started venting poisonous gas to your backyard? Even though it decomposes to dioxygen, it is still harmful in low concentrations. Gaseous (in addition to liquid) ozone is also explosive on its own, though not sure at which conditions.

Comment: Have you considered whether a domestic [swimming pool ozone generator](https://www.google.com/#q=swimming+pool+ozone+generator) would meet your needs? Very common, safe to install and use, and cost effective.

Comment: A general safety rule in any chemical experiment is to keep things dilute and small in quantity. As long as you are below safety limits you should be fine. There are some guidelines in Ozone concentration limit from government directed agencies (you could easily google that). Do not do anything in large scales! Your home is not a manufacturing plant and should not be one.